# Error while refreshing datatables - Cannot reinitialise DataTable

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, datatable

I have a json data that contains 2 arrays with multiple objects and I have put together the following code that enables me to make only one call and split the results into 2 tables. The issue I am having now is I can't refresh the tables anymore. I have tried different options but getting **Cannot reinitialise DataTable** which makes sense, so i guess I am stuck right now.

Code:

```
$(document).ready(function (){
    setInterval (function(){
        $.getJSON("ajax/json.txt", function (pcheckdata){

        <!-- ------------------- Extract Only Alerts ---------------------- -->
            $('#alert-table').dataTable({
                "bJQueryUI": true,
                "data": pcheckdata.alerts,
                "columns": [
                    { "mData": "host" },
                    { "mData": "description" }
                ],
            });

        <!-- ------------------- Extract Only Errors ---------------------- -->
            $('#error-table').dataTable({
                "bJQueryUI": true,
                "data": pcheckdata.errors,
                "columns": [
                    { data: 'host' },
                    { data: 'description' }
                ],
            });
        });
    }, 1000);
});
```

My JSON Structure

```
{
    "alerts": [
        {
            "host": "server1",
            "description": "Engine Alive"
        },
        {
            "host": "ftpserver",
            "description": "Low free disk space"
        }
    ],

    "errors": [
        {
            "host": "server3",
            "description": "Can't connect to MySQL server"
        },
        {
            "host": "server4",
            "description": "SSQL timeout expired"
        }
    ]
}
```

HTML Bit:

```
<table id="alert-table" class="display" cellspacing="0">
    <thead class="t-headers">
        <tr>
            <th>HOST</th>
            <th>DESCRIPTION</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
</table>

<table id="error-table" class="display" cellspacing="0">
    <thead class="t-headers">
        <tr>
            <th>HOST</th>
            <th>ERROR DESCRIPTION</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
</table>
```

I would love to know if there is a way to refresh the 2 tables at the same time since the data will only be fetched once or is it better to use purely JQUERY and forget about datatables as it seems to be giving me headache

Comment: can you show me the part of html that have both ID? I use dataTables too.

Comment: I have added the table bit. It's just basic table structure

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why do you want to reinit whole table, just create table once and on ajax callback, clear the table and add the data. Which version of datatable are you using? I used the old function to clear and add data, with new table it will differ but you  know the idea.

Here is an example:

```
$(document).ready(function (){

    //Init datatables without data

            <!-- ------------------- Extract Only Alerts ---------------------- -->
          var alertTable =  $('#alert-table').dataTable({
                "bJQueryUI": true,

                "columns": [
                    { "mData": "host" },
                    { "mData": "description" }
                ],
            });

        <!-- ------------------- Extract Only Errors ---------------------- -->
           var errorTable = $('#error-table').dataTable({
                "bJQueryUI": true,

                "columns": [
                    { data: 'host' },
                    { data: 'description' }
                ],
            });

    setInterval (function(){
        $.getJSON("ajax/json.txt", function (pcheckdata){

        alertTable.fnClearTable(); //New API then alertTable.clear().draw();
        alertTable.fnAddData(pcheckdata.alerts); //New API then alertTable.row.add(pcheckdata.alerts);
        alertTable.fnAdjustColumnSizing(); //New API then alertTable.columns.adjust().draw();

        errorTable.fnClearTable(); //New API then errorTable.clear().draw();
        errorTable.fnAddData(pcheckdata.errors); //New API then errorTable.row.add(pcheckdata.errors);
        errorTable.fnAdjustColumnSizing();////New API then errorTable.columns.adjust().draw()

        });
    }, 1000);
});
```

Another way is check if datatables are already init.

```
$(document).ready(function (){
    setInterval (function(){
        $.getJSON("ajax/json.txt", function (pcheckdata){
        //Is datatable already init.
        if ( ! $.fn.DataTable.isDataTable( '#alert-table' ) ) {

        <!-- ------------------- Extract Only Alerts ---------------------- -->
            $('#alert-table').dataTable({
                "bJQueryUI": true,
                "data": pcheckdata.alerts,
                "columns": [
                    { "mData": "host" },
                    { "mData": "description" }
                ],
            });
       }else
       {
           $('#alert-table').dataTable().clear().draw();
            $('#alert-table').dataTable().row.add(pcheckdata.alerts);
            $('#alert-table').dataTable().columns.adjust().draw();
       }
        if ( ! $.fn.DataTable.isDataTable( '#error-table' ) ) {
        <!-- ------------------- Extract Only Errors ---------------------- -->
            $('#error-table').dataTable({
                "bJQueryUI": true,
                "data": pcheckdata.errors,
                "columns": [
                    { data: 'host' },
                    { data: 'description' }
                ],
            });
       }else
        {
           $('#error-table').dataTable().clear().draw();
            $('#error-table').dataTable().row.add(pcheckdata.errors);
            $('#error-table').dataTable().columns.adjust().draw();
        }

        });
    }, 1000);
});
```

Comment: interesting! I have seen seen similar code like this, so will try it out. I use the latest version 1.10.2

Comment: tell us if its work or no we will try to make solved your problem

Comment: sure i will. please just give me about 30mins time, rushing out now. Thanks and much appreciated.

Comment: you are a star :), I will go with your first option and also update the code with the new API's and let you know if all OK. I took out a lot of other codes just to make this question clearer like **fnRowCallback** to change row background color if it meets a column condition, **aoColumnDefs** to hide some columns, **mRender** to add a button to a column based on a column condition and **fnServerData** to display nothing if json data returned is either null or empty. Please see [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ypjbd8ma/) if this is all OK. thanks

Comment: Quickly checked fiddle code, looks ok to me. You can post new question if there is any problem you get stuck with. Here is an interesting link to match new api calls if you go for new api. https://datatables.net/upgrade/1.10-convert

Comment: Ok thanks, the new API's not working, getting alertTable.clear is not a function but the old once is working. Strange